# Is it possible to use jquery ui controls instead of web controls in asp .net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, user-interface, webforms

I want to use only jquery ui controls in my web app and handle the raised events of controls in my c# code (not in javascript). I'm new in web programming so sorry if my question is too dummy. Also i want to design my web form with jquery controls as i do it with web controls from toolbox. Is it possible? 
Or is there any alternatives to create beautiful ui in asp net web forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any controls you want. However, non asp.net controls will not postback to your server. You will need to manually call the `__doPostBack();` asp.net method using javascript. Also, since none of you controls will be wired to do postbacks using the built in asp.net mechanism, you will need to force your page to generate that code for you by calling something like this:

```
var cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

I hope this helps